# Datetime not recorded correctly with activemodel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, activerecord

I have a problem for saving my datetime with activerecord on ruby 2.0 and rails 3.2

I have started getting the error below :

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: encrypted_password, reset_password_token, reset_password_sent_at(1i), reset_password_sent_at(2i), reset_password_sent_at(3i), reset_password_sent_at(4i), reset_password_sent_at(5i)
```

It appends on every datetime fields.

Comment: Add your fields to `attr_accessible` if you want to let users set them.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your model:

```
attr_accessible :encrypted_password, :reset_password_token, :reset_password_sent_at
```

That will allow you to assign values to these attributes from "the outside" like you try to do.